# laravel get article id

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have an articles table and a likes table. Im trying to save the id of all the articles the user likes to return to them later on a dashboard. How do i take the id made on the articles table and add it to the likes table under article_id?

```
public function store()
{
    $request = Request::all();


    $likes = new like();
    $likes ->article_id = Auth::article()->id;
    $likes->user_id =   Auth::user()->id;
    $name = Auth::user()->name;
    $likes->save();

    return redirect('article');



}

   $table->foreign('article_id')
            ->references('id')
            ->on('articles');
```

Comment: when the article is created, it makes an ID. how do i add that id to the likes table?

Comment: I have added answer... Check and comment...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you have most of the code wrong. From the information you have given, I would have at least the following:

- Article model, so you can do:

  - `$article = Article::find($id);` where `$id` is the ID of the article
  - `$articleLikes = $article->likes();` where `likes()` is defined in 
    Article model as:

`public function likes() {
  return Like::where('article_id', $this->id)->get();
}`

- Like model, so you can do

  - `$like = new Like;`
  - `$like->user_id = Auth::user()->id;`
  - `$like->article_id = $article->id;`
  - `$like->save();`
- Article controller, so you can:

  - Show all articles (by returning an index view with all articles)

    - `public function index()`
  - Create an article (by returning a create article view)

    - `public function create()`
  - Show an article (by returning a show article view)

    - `public function show($id)` where `$id` is the ID of the article
  - Edit an article (by returning an edit article view)

    - `public function edit($id)` where `$id` is the ID of the article
  - Store an article (by inserting an article into DB)

    - `public function store(Request $request)` where `$request` is POST data
  - Update an article (by updating an article in DB)

    - `public function update(Request $request)` where `$request` is POST data
  - Destroy an article (by deleting an article in DB)

    - `public function destroy($id)` where `$id` is the ID of the article

Here's a good video tutorial series to get you started in Laravel 5: https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-fundamentals

Edit: More information

How to get all the article ids that the user has liked:

```
$userId = Auth::user()->id;
$likes = Like::where(user_id, $userId)->get();

$articleIds = new \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection;
foreach($likes as $like) {
  $articleIds.add($like->article_id);
}

// Now $articleIds should contain all the IDs of articles 
// that the currently logged in user has liked.
```

Comment: i have models created for likes and article...are you saying what i had written under the (store) in article controller needs to be written inside the actual model pages? whenever i put $article->id; it tells me that article is not defined

Comment: @RickiMoore it tells you article is not defined because you haven't defined the $article variable in your scope.

Answer (score 1):

Most of code is wrong.

So if You want create an article:

```
$Article = new Article();
$Article->title = Request::input('title');
$Article->contents = Request::input('content');
$Article->save();
```

If You want create a record in likes table using Like model:

```
$Like = new Like();
$Like->article_id = $Article->id;
$Like->user_id = Auth::user()->id; // of course if You're using Auth
$Like->save();
```

Comment: When i add $article->id; it tells me that the article variable is not defined?

Comment: Because You don't save it or don't select it (.find() or where()) to have access to object.

Answer (score 0):

When the addition of Artical is completed just get the last insert id and store it into the likes table.

Something like this

```
$art = new Article();
$art->name = "Test";
$art->save();
```

add the following line in the above... For example something like this

```
$art = new Article();
$art->name = "Test";
$art->save();
$artId = $art->id;
```

`$art->id` will get the last insert id of the article, Now you can store that id into likes table...